# The jump set of $SBV$ function over a hyper surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Assume $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ is open bounded, smooth boundary. Also assume $S\subset \Omega$ is a smooth hyper surface such that $0<\mathcal H^{N-1}(S)<+\infty$.

Now, given a **positive** function $u\in SBV(\Omega)$ and define function $\tau (x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,S)$ for $x\in\Omega$. My question: do we have the following equality hold?
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\left\{\sup_{s\in(t/2,t)}\left\{\int_{\{y:\tau(y)=s\}} u(y)\,d\mathcal H^{N-1} \right\}\right\}= \int_S(u^+(x)+u^-(x))d\mathcal H^{N-1}
$$
The question is clear when $N=1$. But I got stuck on case $N>1$.

Any help is really welcome!

---

PS: the definition
$$
u^+(x):=\inf\{s\in[-\infty,+\infty]:\,\,\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{\mathcal{H}^N(\{y\in B(x,r):\,\, u(y)>s\})}{r^N}=0\},
$$
$$
u^-(x):=\sup\{s\in[-\infty,+\infty]:\,\,\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{\mathcal{H}^N(\{y\in B(x,r):\,\, u(y)<s\})}{r^N}=0\},
$$